# MYSQL group by on splitted array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, compare, left-join

I have a table `event` with a column `organizer`. The column organizer is an array of ID-Ints (f.e.: "10,920,527"). In a second table (`user`) the ids gets connected with names.

I need a MYSQL Query which can give me a string of the names of the event organizers.
So f.e.:

```sql
SELECT event.*, group_concat(user.forname, ' ', user.surname) as real_names
FROM   event 
LEFT   JOIN user ON event.organizer=user.id 
WHERE  event.id='" . $get_id . "' 
GROUP  BY event.id
```

So the problem here is now: `event`.`organizer` is an Array and I want to compare each value of the array with all `user`.`id`'s.

I am not sure if this is possible in MYSQL but I think If its possible it will be much shorter than to implode them in PHP where I would need another query to get all the usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use FIND_IN_SET function of mysql, Take a look to below code

```
SELECT event.*, group_concat(user.forname, ' ', user.surname) as real_names
FROM   event 
LEFT   JOIN user ON FIND_IN_SET(event.organizer, user.id) > 0
WHERE  event.id='" . $get_id . "' 
GROUP  BY event.id
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem properly, you need to redesign your database appropriately.

If each user can be an organizer for different events and each event can be organized by different user (many-to-many relationship), you need to create another (pivot) table like `user_event`: user_id, event_id. So to make your query you will need to join this table by event_id and then join user table by user_id.

```
SELECT event.*, group_concat(user.forname, ' ', user.surname) as real_names
FROM   event 
LEFT  JOIN user_event ON event.id=user_event.event_id
LEFT  JOIN user ON user_event.user_id=user.id
WHERE  event.id='" . $get_id . "' 
GROUP  BY event.id
```